# custom title on facebook sharer

Tags: facebook-sharer

I am creating a page , which has a Facebook share button, 
Now I want to share a youtube video but the title of that video in facebook page should be my custom word.

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://youtu.be/kOoKAbk_Wt4
&t=Custom title" target="_blank">Share Video</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible using the `u` parameter. As long as you supply that parameter it will take OG metadata from the page.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing and figured out you can do it with the feed dialog, not with the sharer: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog